# How to put a literal array into dynamic memory using memcpy? xcode bug?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4.2, memcpy

I want to put a literal array into a dynamic memory.

```
double *rgb = (double*)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(rgb, (double []){1,2,3}, sizeof(rgb));
```

but I get the error:  Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation.

But if I do this:

```
double *rgb = (double*)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(rgb, (double []){1}, sizeof(rgb));
```

The compiler yields no errors?  Why?

Is Objective-c bugged ... or am I missing something?

Comment: cleared it up... please look at the memcpy

Comment: Could you let us know what compiler and version you're using? Would be good to know for future reference, as the fact that `memcpy` is a macro (`#define`) is stdlib/compiler dependent and comes as a surprise to me.

Comment: xcode 4.2 and tagged

Comment: xcode is an IDE, not a compiler. I think xcode uses LLVM/clang by default nowadays, GCC in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

> Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation.

`memcpy()` is apparently implemented by your compiler/stdlib as a preprocessor function macro (i.e. a `#define` somewhere in your lib's header files). So this line

```
memcpy(rgb, (double []){1,2,3}, sizeof(rgb));
```

is reading the commas inside and considering them as argument separators (remember, the preprocessor knows nothing about the C code except what a token is). To the preprocessor, you have 5 arguments `rgb`, `(double []){1`, `2`, `3}`, and `sizeof(rgb)`. It expects 3 arguments.

---

With regard to how to initialise dynamic memory, this works with `gcc` in `c99` standard mode:

```
double *rgb = (double*)malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(rgb, (double []){1,2,3}, 3 * sizeof(double));
```

... so apparently gcc's stdlib does *not* use a macro for `memcpy`.

Also note that `sizeof(rgb)` = 4 or 8, because `rgb` is a *pointer*: `sizeof` a pointer is the size of a memory address, not of the length of the array. Thus, I used `3 * sizeof(double)` in the `memcpy` call.

In a more complex program, you would have to pass the length of the array around along with a pointer to the array, in order for that information to be available to code that manipulates the array.

For your particular compiler, this may be a solution (although if this isn't optimised away, it's less efficient—presumably you wouldn't be hard-coding initialisation data that's large enough for this to matter?):

```
double rgb_initial[] = {1, 2, 3};
double * rgb = (double *) malloc(3 * sizeof(double));
memcpy(rgb, rgb_initial, 3 * sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should work with C99, my guess is that you use an older standard.

Before C99 you need to hold the input in a cost variable like this:

```
const double stuff[] = {1, 2, 3};
memcpy(rgb, stuff, 3*sizeof(double));
```

Comment: This `sizeof(rgb)` only copies 4 or 8 bytes depending on the system's pointer width.

Comment: Happens so fast that one focusses too much on one problem... :)